# How can I filter rows based on a regex from one column to another

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
  ClientCode                                           FileName
0      123     123--filename
1      234     456--filename
2      345     345--filename
3      456     123--filename
4      567     567--filename
```

Basically I need to return the rows where ClientCode is NOT IN the filename field

That would return rows 1,3 on above sample

However I dont know if this is even possible with a simple expression in pandas filtering

Comment: `.str.split('--')` and convert the correct dtype

Comment: I dont understand, split only splits! it wont filter

Comment: Yes, split then compare?

Comment: can you paste the entire solution? how would  the filtering expression be?  the str.split would create another coluumn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:-

```
df[~df['ClientCode'].eq(df['FileName'].str.split('--',expand=True)[0].astype(int))]
```